# onListItemClick for dynamically changing list item

Tags: android, android-listview

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    int selection  = position;

    switch (selection)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            String toast=" 1 clicked";
            DisplayToast(toast);

        }
        break;
       case 1:
        {
            String toast=" 2 clicked";
            DisplayToast(toast);

        }
        break;
    }
}
```

This is the code I am using for my OnListItemClick() in List Activity.

My Problem is my List item is populated dynamically and hence I don't know how many items would be there in the list.

I cannot use switch statement in that case.So. How can I distinguish which item was clicked in a dynamically changing list.

Comment: What should happen when a listItem is clicked? Just display a toast??

Comment: what exactly you want to do with it.
However "position" gives you the index of clicked listItem and this is what we use to distinguish and do our stuff on.

Comment: yes.. If i click on any item from the list a toast should be displayed..

Comment: What kind of adapter are you using? CursorAdapter, ArrayAdapter? And what do you want to show in your toast?

Comment: @nistv4n i am using ArrayAdapter, I want get the text from the selected item and display it as a toast

Comment: @Sayyam - I am not sure How many items would be there in the list as it is updated dynamically.. hence I do not want to hard code using switch-case

Comment: I dont think its a good practice to have an independent action for each of the elements in your list unless its a really small static list. Now answering your question, you can distiguish wich element was clicked by the position, and if you want to retrieve the item that was clicked you can use the method getItem from your adapter (adapter.getItem(position); )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an onItemClickListener like this:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();           
}

});
```

So you can get the text of your currently selected item by getItemAtPosition(position).toString().

Or if you make your own ArrayAdapter, you can implement the getItem(position) method, which can return with anything about your adapter item.

Answer (score 0):

This will get the Text from the selected textview and display it in a Toast.

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    String toast= ((TextView)v).getText();
    DisplayToast(toast);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code

```
String toast = " " + ++position + " clicked";
DisplayToast(toast);
```